# How to create an instance of an Interface(access to Interface)

Tags: c#

I have an Interface like this:

```
namespace QuickRoutes.Model.Utilities
{
    public interface IRoutesManager
    {
        bool ImportRoute(Stream inputStream, string fileName);
        List<Route> GetAllRoutes();
        List<Route> GetAllRoutesForDate(DateTime from, DateTime to);
        void DeleteRoute(string routeName);
        void DeleteAllRoutes();

    }
}
```

and I want to access to i.e ImportRoute function from my Form but I cant access to this Function and an error occured like this:
**cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface**
How can I access to these functions?

Comment: I think you need to learn OOPS concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an *implementation* of the interface which defines the actual behaviour. The interface itself only declares the members - as you can see, there's no code there to say what to do.

Your `Form` can either create an instance of some implementation, or be given it - quite possibly *only* as an `IRoutesManager`, so that the form itself doesn't need to care about which implementation it's using.

Answer (score 1):

You never create instances of interfaces, interfaces are just contracts. What you would do is :-

```
public class MyRouteManager : IRoutesManager
{ 
    bool ImportRoute(Stream inputStream, string fileName)
    { code here etc etc } 
    List<Route> GetAllRoutes();
    List<Route> GetAllRoutesForDate(DateTime from, DateTime to);
    void DeleteRoute(string routeName);
    void DeleteAllRoutes();

}
```

You coudl also change the word interface to class if its a class you wish instead.